# Java high resolution sleeping

Tags: java, timer

I want to simulate a clock that ticks on a high frequency in Java. We can think of it as a 1Mhz CPU clock for example. This can be achieved with this code:

```
    // 1000 nanoseconds between ticks.
    final long period = 1000;
    this.runnable = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            long last = System.nanoTime();
            while (true) {
                long now = System.nanoTime();
                if (now - last > period) {
                    last = now;
                    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getId() + " ticked at:" + now);
                }
            }

        }
    };
    this.thread = new Thread(this.runnable);
    this.thread.start();
```

The problem with this code is that it is a high CPU consumer as the thread is running constantly. I want to make the thread to sleep for some time between subsequent time checks, something like the code below:

```
    // 1000 nanoseconds between ticks.
    final long period = 1000;
    this.runnable = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            long last = System.nanoTime();
            while (true) {
                long now = System.nanoTime();
                if (now - last > period) {
                    last = now;
                    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getId() + " ticked at:" + now);
                }
            }
            // here 4 is arbitrary, it determines checks frequency
            LockSupport.parkNanos(period / 4);
        }
    };
    this.thread = new Thread(this.runnable);
    this.thread.start();
```

The problem in this approach is that the thread is halted for too long (> 1ms in windows). The same thing happens if I use `Thread.sleep(0, period / 4);`.
I understand the `Thread.sleep` and `LockSupport.parkNanos` can only guarantee the minimum time to sleep/halt.
Is there a way to achieve what I want, i.e: tick the lock at this frequency without making the thread to run constantly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## `ScheduledExecutorService`

In modern Java, we rarely need to address `Thread` directly. Instead, use the Executor framework added to Java 5.

Part of that framework is  [`ScheduledExecutorService`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html). You can ask that a task should be executed repeatedly between a specified period of time.

Some important points:

- Obviously your task’s code must be *very* brief, executing in less than a microsecond. This may well be unrealistic.
- You have a choice of two scheduling methods: [`scheduleAtFixedRate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html#scheduleAtFixedRate(java.lang.Runnable,long,long,java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)) and [`scheduleWithFixedDelay`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html#scheduleWithFixedDelay(java.lang.Runnable,long,long,java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)). I suspect you want the first. But study both to decide for yourself.
- The **scheduling of your task will *not* be perfect**. Both the host OS and the JVM may introduce delays. If you want perfect timing, you must use a [real-time system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_time_Java).
- I suspect your desired timeframe of a microsecond is approaching the limit of the hardware clock and software scheduler. At that granularity of time, I do not know if this approach will satisfactorily meet your needs.
- You must be careful to shutdown your executor service. Otherwise its backing pool of threads may run indefinitely, like a zombie ‍♂️. Here we use try-with-resources syntax to close automatically.

Here is some example code in [Java 20](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_20).

```java
AtomicLong count = new AtomicLong( 0L );
try (
        ScheduledExecutorService ses = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor() ;
)
{
    Runnable task = count :: incrementAndGet;
    ses.scheduleAtFixedRate( task , 0L , 1L , TimeUnit.MICROSECONDS ); // 1,000 nanos = 1 micro.
    try { Thread.sleep( Duration.ofMillis( 10 ) ); } catch ( InterruptedException e ) { throw new RuntimeException( e ); }
}
// We expect around 1,000 per millisecond in our count.
System.out.println( "count = " + count );
```

When run:

> count = 13226

We expect about 1,000 count for every millisecond. For ten milliseconds, we would expect about 10,000 in our count. I am getting results of 10,xxx to 13,xxx in the count when run within IntelliJ in Java 20 on an [Apple M1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_M1) MacBook Pro.

Comment: Neat, I wasn’t aware that ExecutorService now extends AutoCloseable.

Comment: @VGR And `Thread.sleep` now takes a `java.time.Duration`. All part of the work being done for [*Project Loom*](https://wiki.openjdk.org/display/loom/Main).